# LaTeX code in knitr figure caption

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm trying to insert LaTeX code into a figure caption created by knitr. I have the code below in a .Rnw file and I'm converting it to a .tex file using knitr:

```
<<my_plot, fig.cap="X is $\leq$1 and Y is $\geq$2">>=

plot(1,2)

@
```

Code as it stands give an error. How can I use insert the LaTeX code into the figure caption?

Comment: And the error is...? (You probably want `$\leq 1$` and `$\geq 2$` for the spacing.) Oh, and does it work if you double the backslashes; `$\\leq 1$` and `$\\geq 2$`?

Comment: Doubling the backslashes is what you need.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Why not move the comment to an answer? I think you are absolutely correct.